# Kibana Wildcard "Not" Match in filter

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

This is a straightforward use case that was surprisingly difficult to find a simple answer.

**Using an ELK stack for log monitoring, how do I create a "not xyz" wildcard filter?**

For example, when developing a Django app a "not Django" filter is pretty critical.

There are lots of examples for [keyword searches](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/using-must-not-and-wildcard-to-search/134590/2) and [es filters](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/not-filter-using-a-wildcard/144184/3) - but if you just want to use the tool without a primer in elasticsearch, there isn't a lot of great copypasta available.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple filter for "exclude Django":

```html
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "wildcard": {
          "log.logger": "django*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. create a new filter from a dashboard via **add filter** >> **Edit as Query DSL**
2. copy paste this in (adjust `django*` as needed)
3. Toggle "Use Custom Label" and give the filter a readable name such as "exclude Django"